# How to start Apple Hardware Test without Apple Software Disk (MBP13 mid-2010)?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My question is very simple. I have some trouble on my MBP13 mid-2010 (MC375LL/A) and I want to diagnose it using the Apple Hardware Test.

I try to hold the D key down during restart of the MBP but nothing happens. I think it is due to the fact that I need to use the DVD 2 coming with the MBP. Unfortunately I don't have the DVD currently.

I try to use Internet Recovery (by holding "Option+D") but it seems that Apple Hardware Test does not support my MBP...

So I am looking for a solution to achieve this diagnostic without the original DVD.

**Edit:** My MBP is currently running on OSX Maverick (10.9.1).

Comment: Based on [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1478), your computer **does** support Internet Recovery. Did you update the firmware?

Comment: @Thecafremo I just verify the version of the ROM in my MBP and it is `MBP71.0039.BOE`. Thus it seems to be ok...

Comment: I forget to say that my MBP is currently running on Maverick (10.9.1).

Comment: +1 I had (and still have) the exact same problem with "MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010)"; now running 10.10.1 (with latest firmware).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By knowing your exact Model Identifier (MacBokPro?,?) you could look in to [this data base](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest) for the correct version of AHT to download.

Examples:

```
MacBookPro1,1 3A106
MacBookPro1,1 3A107
MacBookPro2,1 Mac-F42189C8
MacBookPro2,2 Mac-F42187C8
MacBookPro3,1 Mac-F42388C8
MacBookPro3,1 Mac-F4238BC8
MacBookPro4,1 Mac-F42C86C8
MacBookPro4,1 Mac-F42C89C8
MacBookPro5,1 Mac-F42D86A9
MacBookPro5,1 Mac-F42D86C8
MacBookPro5,2 Mac-F2268EC8
MacBookPro5,3 Mac-F22587C8
MacBookPro5,4 Mac-F22587A1
MacBookPro5,5 Mac-F2268AC8
MacBookPro6,1 Mac-F22589C8
MacBookPro6,2 Mac-F22586C8
MacBookPro7,1 Mac-F222BEC8
MacBookPro8,1 Mac-94245B3640C91C81
MacBookPro8,2 Mac-94245A3940C91C80
MacBookPro8,3 Mac-942459F5819B171B
MacBookPro9,1 Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E
MacBookPro9,2 Mac-6F01561E16C75D06
MacBookPro10,1 Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer the question of how to get AHT and assuming your Mac is indeed a 13inch mid-2010 MacBook Pro your model is MacBookPro7,1 and for that model you can download AHT from Apple with the link below and follow my steps below to put it on a flash drive.

[Apple AHT for MacBookPro7,1 - 022-4653-A.dmg](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-4653-A.dmg) - do not use unless you've verified you indeed have a MacBookPro7,1, it won't mess up your computer if it isn't, it just won't boot.

To some these steps may not make sense, I'm just reformatting what I was told and worked when I did this for my iMac to a guide for this specific MacBook Pro, I don't dare wipe my flash drive to try another method as I don't want to loose its power. Continuing on...

**(your flash drive will be WIPED)**
1. Insert your flash drive of at least 16MB capacity and open *Disk Utility* then select your flash drive on the left and go to the *Partition* tab.
2. Select *1 Partition* in the drop down then go to *Options...* and select *GUID Partition Table* then verify *Format* is set to *Mac OS Extended (Journaled)*
3. Finally enter a name for your drive (I recommend something simple like *AHT-FD*, do not use spaces) and click *Apply*
4. After formatting is finished mount (double click) the [022-4653-A.dmg](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-4653-A.dmg) you downloaded and copy everything to your freshly formatted *AHT-FD* flash drive.
5. In *Finder* open *Go* in the menu bar and select *Go to Folder...* then paste */Volumes/AHT-FD/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/* and click *Go*
6. Copy the *diags.efi* file and paste it to the root of your *AHT-FD* flash drive.
7. For the final step open *Terminal* and paste this code then enter your password, **your computer will immediately reboot after the command completes, save any work first**

```
cd /Volumes/AHT-FD/ && sudo bless --mount /Volumes/AHT-FD --setBoot --file diags.efi && sudo reboot
```

You should now be booting into AHT...
After you are finished shut down your computer, remove the flash drive, and at the start up chhime hold down *Option* on your keyboard and select your Mac's hard drive again.

Source for all this information: [Here](http://rivenbyfive.blogspot.com/2012/01/download-and-run-apple-hardware-test.html) and [here](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest).

Comment: The latter link, to the github project, is excellent, and pointed me straight to the right download link, direct from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Apple Support Page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904) these Mac's are eligible for Internet Recovery:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)
- iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011)
- MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010)
- **MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)**
- Mac mini (Mid 2010)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch and 17-inch, Mid 2010)
- iMac (21.5-inch and 27-inch, Mid 2010)
- MacBook Air (11-inch and 13-inch, Late 2010)

Upgrade your MBP with [EFI Firmware Update 2.5 for MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1478) to enable it.

Comment: My ROM version and SMC version are: `MBP71.0039.B0E` and `1.62f7`. Considering this [table](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237), my MBP is up to date. Unfortunately I can't start the AHT. Notice that the Firmware update proposed by Apple is for Lion and in my case my MBP is running on Maverick (10.9.1).

Comment: I had (and still have) the exact same problem with "MacBook Pro (15-inch and 17-inch, Mid 2010)" => even with updated firmware, the internet recovery ("option+D") begins, but reports that "this mac is not supported" (and I can't locate the disk 1/2 that came with the mac originally)

Answer (score -2):

Here we can find a list of AHTs:
https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest